# Inconsistent results from ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, query-string, constants, mismatch

I have a somewhat unnerving problem when using constant values. I have a simple page called "test.asp" which sets a variable to a constant and then to a querystring value (if it exists). Then a select case checks if the variable matches the constant and outputs a message "matched". The problem is that asp does not recognise when the querystring value is the same as the constant.
I have run 2 attempts, "test.asp" and "test.asp?SortField=1". The first attempt runs as expected but the second attempt reports that 1 is not the same as 1.
The code for this page is as follows.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<head></head>
<body>

<%
const cSortFielda = 1
dim vSortField

vSortField = cSortFielda
if not isempty(Request("SortField")) then
    vSortField = Request("SortField")
    end if

select case vSortField
    case cSortFielda
        response.write "matched</br>"

    case else
        response.write "failed</br>"
        response.write "vSortField = " & vSortField & "(" & asc(vSortField) & ") </br>"
        response.write "cSortFielda = " & cSortFielda & "(" & asc(cSortFielda) & ") </br>"
        response.write "vSortField = cSortFielda is " & (vSortField = cSortFielda) & "</br>"

        end select
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious or is asp classic at fault?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing a string with a number.  You need to make sure they are consistent.  So either change this line:

```
const cSortFielda = 1
```

To:

```
const cSortFielda = "1"
```

Or change this line:

```
vSortField = Request("SortField")
```

To:

```
vSortField = CLng(Request("SortField"))
```

The first example compares string to string, and the second example compares number to number.

Comment: Ah of course! thank you! and thank you for such a concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

All variables are variants in VBScript unless you specify a literal value to that variable.

So const CSortFielda is a number.

But vSortField is a variant which holds the STRING of the value of the SortField query string item

Either change the const value to be a string

```
Const cSortFields = "1"
```

Or parse SortField as a number

```
If Not isEmpty(Request("SortField")) then
    If IsNumeric(Request("SortField")) then
        vSortField = CLng(Request("SortField"))
    End If
End If
```

I would also suggest specifying that the field comes from the querystring, although that's not related to your actual problem:

```
Request.QueryString.Item("SortField")
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing string against integer results in false. Add these and you would see.

```
Response.write TypeName(vSortField) & "<br/>"
Response.Write TypeName(cSortFielda) & "<br/>"
```

Make sure that both variables are of same type or convert before comparing. Since you are dealing with QueryString, it would be easier to use string type i.e. `const cSortFielda = "1"`.